# Compare Guitar Pro files

Tags: comparison, diff

I am looking for a tool that can diff/compare Guitar Pro (5) files. Which of these file types should/could I use to compare tablatures? GP5 exports these file types:

- MIDI
- ASCII
- MusicXML
- GP5

These are probably not so good for comparison, but can be exported from GP5:

- Wave
- BMP
- PDF

What is the best way to diff tablatures?

**UPDATE**
To make my question a bit clearer: I am looking for a comparison tool which gives me a nice overview of what has changed in the tablature. I already know *that* the files are different, but I want to know *what* is the difference between the two files. I am looking in a contextual matter, not in bits and bytes.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII or MusicXML might be good, as they are plain text. I suspect that if they are created by different people though, almost everything will be different.

I'd export both as ascii to start with, then just run

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

to compare. If you don't have the standard unix tools available for whatever reason, then I believe dc.exe is available for Windows.

Comment: Exporting to ASCII forces me to diff every track of the GP separately. So if I have 6 instruments, I need to do 12 manual exports and 6 diffs. Which is far from optimal I think. MusicXML is doable, but it doesn't give me a correct overview of what is happening, because it is a large file with a lot of irrelevant information. Every note is defined by a tag or 8.